# Scrape text from 2nd <BR>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have html extract below, note, the two td's repeat for each row I need to capture.

```
<table class="ent">
<tbody class=""><tr class="tablestyle">

    <td class="hide_on_mobile">  <a href="../" class="">
        <img class="ProductImage" src="https://.."></a>
    </td>
    <td class="hide_on_mobile" align="center">
        <strong class="">
            <span style="font-size:1.4em;" class="">Scraped okay - col0</span>
                <br>
                <br>Scrape this text - col1</strong><br>
                <br><i><span style="color:indigo;" class="">Scrape this text - col2
                <br class="">
                <br>Next Event: Scrape this text -col3</span></i>
    </td>
```

I need to capture 4 different data pieces col0, col1, col2, col3

I have already got col0 working.  I need to capture col1,col2,col3

I'm trying to use the BR i.e 
after span

take the text after 2nd BR after for col1

take the text after 3rd BR after for col2

take the text after 5th BR after for col3

I cant get col1 working with br > br.  Any ideas how I can solve this?

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import requestsnt
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http:/*"

r = requests.get(url)
source = r.text
t = datetime.datetime.now().date()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

row_count=200

row_marker = 0

new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col0", "col1", "col2","col3", "DateAdded"], index = range(0,row_count)) # I don't know the number of rows

# For col0
column_marker = 0
for layout in soup.select("strong > span"):
            new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = layout.text.strip()
            new_table.iat[row_marker,4] = t
            row_marker +=1

# For col 1

column_marker = 1
row_marker = 0
for layout in soup.select("strong > span > br > br"):
            new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = layout.text.strip()
            row_marker +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#since you said there are multiple trs
trs = data.find_all('tr')


for tr in trs:
    l = []
    td =  tr.find_all('td')
    #since first td will never have data.. acc to the above posted ques 
    for tags in td[1]:
        try:
            if tags.text:
                print(tags.text)
                l.extend((tags.text).split('\n'))
        except:
            pass

#once there are more trs keep below code inside the loop
#then store the data in a df..since each loop will give new list
str_data = [' '.join(s.split()) for s in l if s]        
str_data.remove('')
print(str_data)
```

Output

```
['Scraped okay - col0',
 'Scrape this text - col1',
 'Scrape this text - col2',
 'Next Event: Scrape this text -col3']
```